# How can I get the maximum of multiple columns in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite database containing 2 tables: `album` and `photo`. An album, is basically just a collection of photos, represented by a foreign key in `photo`. Each photo holds 3 timestamps: created, updated, deleted.

```
sqlite> SELECT id, title FROM album;

id          title
----------  ----------------
1           Beach party 2018
2           Dad's 60th birth

sqlite> SELECT id, album, ts_created, ts_updated, ts_deleted FROM photo;

id          album       ts_created  ts_updated  ts_deleted
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           1538649250              1538649274
2           1           1538649250  1538649261
3           1           1538649250
4           1           1538649250  1538649267
5           1           1538649250  1538649267
6           2           1538649962
7           2           1538649962
```

When displaying the album in the application, I want to show the title, and the date that the last photo "event" (add, edit, remove, etc.), e.g.

> **Beach party 2018**
>
> *Edited on: Thu Oct  4 10:34:34 UTC 2018*

How can I get this information from the timestamps in the `photo` table ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of the `max` builtin function helps here. From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc):

> Note that max() is a simple function when it has 2 or more arguments but operates as an aggregate function if given only a single argument.

Also note that, since our timestamps can be NULL, and `max` returns NULL if any value is NULL, we need to use `coalesce` to ensure NULL columns don't break the outer `max`.

```
SELECT album.id,
       album.title,
       max(
           max(coalesce(photo.ts_created, 0)),
           max(coalesce(photo.ts_updated, 0)),
           max(coalesce(photo.ts_deleted, 0))
       ) AS ts_content
  FROM album,
       photo
 WHERE album.id = photo.album
 GROUP BY album.id;


id          title             ts_content
----------  ----------------  ----------
1           Beach party 2018  1538649274
2           Dad's 60th birth  1538649962
```